# Expectation of linear form multiplied by quadratic form for MVN distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, machine-learning

Assume that $\bf{x}$ is a random vector that is distributed multivariate normal with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. Let $\bf{A}$ be a matrix of constants.

I'm trying to prove that

$$
\operatorname{Cov}[\bf{x}, \bf{x}^T \bf{A} \bf{x}] = 2 \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \bf{A} \boldsymbol{\mu}
$$

In the process of simplifying the expression, I've encountered the expectation of the product:

$$
\operatorname{E}[\bf{x} \bf{x}^T \bf{A} \bf{x}]
$$

Given the assumption of a MVN distribution, can this be simplified?